# PHP collecting multiple form data having increment ids

Tags: php, html

i am trying to get the data from my form using loop. The following code does not work

> HTML code :-

```
<tr  name="row_1" id="row_1">
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="SText" contenteditable="true" value="Basic" name="SText_1" id="SText_1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="SAmount" contenteditable="true" value="6000.00" name="SAmount_1" id="SAmount_1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr  name="row_2" id="row_2">
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="SText" contenteditable="true" value="Housing" name="SText_2" id="SText_2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="SAmount" contenteditable="true" value="5000.00" name="SAmount_2" id="SAmount_2" /></td>
</tr>
```

> PHP code :-

```
<?php
$i=1;
while ($i<=10) {
   $sText_$i = $_POST['SText_$i'];
   $sAmount_$i =  $_POST['SAmount_$i'];

   //$sText_$i = $_POST['SText_'] . $i ; // dont work either
   //$sAmount_$i =  $_POST['SAmount_'] .$i;
$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: $length = sizeof($_POST["SText"]);
    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
        echo $_POST['SText'][$i];
        echo $_POST['SAmount'][$i];
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### PHP uses the square bracket syntax to convert form inputs into an array

> HTML code :-

```
<tr  name="row_1" id="row_1">
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="SText" contenteditable="true" value="Basic" name="SText[]" id="SText_1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="SAmount" contenteditable="true" value="6000.00" name="SAmount[]" id="SAmount_1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr  name="row_2" id="row_2">
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="SText" contenteditable="true" value="Housing" name="SText[]" id="SText_2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="SAmount" contenteditable="true" value="5000.00" name="SAmount[]" id="SAmount_2" /></td>
</tr>
```

> PHP Code :-

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST["SText"]);
print_r($_POST["SAmount"]);
?>
```

Comment: how will i get this with php loop ?

Comment: This print_r will gives you all SText and SAmount into a array , so you can use simple foreach loop to get single value ..

Comment: First add form before start table then lastly submit it .. and you get values .